# Running a java class that is located on a mapped network drive

Tags: java, unc, network-share

I am trying to figure out whether it is possible to run a java class that is located on a mapped network drive. An example would be:

```
C:\temp\groovy>java p:\Test
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: p:\Test
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: p:\Test
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: p:\Test.  Program will exit.
```

Before trying this, I wanted to see whether I could run a java class file that is on UNC share (java `\\somehost\share\Test`). This did not work either - same error about class def not being found.

Am I doing something wrong or is this really not supported ?

Thanks

Comment: Post the error please. The class not being found, might not be the class that you are attempting to run in the first place. It might simply be a dependency.

Comment: Which class cannot be found? Why not just `cd` to the folder on the network drive?

Comment: I pasted the error. I wanted to be able to run a java class that resides on a UNC share to begin with. Since I ran into errors about Class not being found, I wanted to see if I could map a network drive to that share location and run the java class this way. Unfortunately, that did not work either. But as Matt points out, one can cd into the directory and run it. My original intent was to have common staging area where the java class live and run them from multiple windows machines via the network share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you give a path as part of the class name, Java expects it to be in a package corresponding to the folder hierarchy it's in.

Example:

```
> java z:/Test
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: z:/Test
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: z:.Test
```

Here it is looking for "z:.Test" as the fully qualified class name.

Assuming your Test class is not declared as being in any package, you need to specify the directory on the classpath:

```
java -cp Z:\path Test
```

Comment: In other words, what you supply to the `java` command is not a path or filename, it is a fully-qualified class name.

Answer (score 1):

The java launcher accepts a class as the first non-option argument for locating the main method that is to be invoked.

From the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html):

> By default, the first non-option
>   argument is the name of the class to
>   be invoked. A fully-qualified class
>   name should be used. If the -jar
>   option is specified, the first
>   non-option argument is the name of a
>   JAR archive containing class and
>   resource files for the application,
>   with the startup class indicated by
>   the Main-Class manifest header.
>
> The Java runtime searches for the startup
>   class, and other classes used, in
>   three sets of locations: the bootstrap
>   class path, the installed extensions,
>   and the user class path.

You therefore, cannot provide `p:\Test` as an argument. Instead change the current working directory to `p:\`, and execute `java Test`.

You may use a batch script to change the directory without performing this manually. Or you can package the class into a JAR file (with the required manifest), and provide the `-jar` option to specify the absolute path to the JAR file to the `java` executable; this is preferred if you do not want to manage too many class files.

Edit: You can also use the `-cp` flag as specified by @Dave Costa. This will enable you to do away with the need to change the current directory.